# How can I run a powershell script on a target VM using Terraform's aws_ssm_document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

How can I run a powershell script on a target VM using Terraform's aws_ssm_document ?
AWS has **AWS-RunPowerShellScript** in what looks like a aws_ssm_document command using the portal.
It would be ideal if I could create/run this aws_ssm_document using a powershell script and the Terraform file function.

The **AWS-RunPowerShellScript** document is available, so it should be possible to use the **aws_ssm_document** passing json, to create a document and **aws_ssm_association** to apply the document to a VM.

```
{
    "Document": {
        "Hash": "2142e42a19e0955cc09e43600bf2e633df1917b69d2be9693737dfd62e0fdf61",
        "HashType": "Sha256",
        "Name": "AWS-RunPowerShellScript",
        "Owner": "Amazon",
        "CreatedDate": "2017-08-31T16:52:31.357000-04:00",
        "Status": "Active",
        "DocumentVersion": "1",
        "Description": "Run a PowerShell script or specify the paths to scripts to run.",
        "Parameters": [
            {
                "Name": "commands",
                "Type": "StringList",
                "Description": "(Required) Specify the commands to run or the paths to existing scripts on the instance."
            },
            {
                "Name": "workingDirectory",
                "Type": "String",
                "Description": "(Optional) The path to the working directory on your instance.",
                "DefaultValue": ""
            },
            {
                "Name": "executionTimeout",
                "Type": "String",
                "Description": "(Optional) The time in seconds for a command to be completed before it is considered to have failed. Default is 3600 (1 hour). Maximum is 172800 (48 hours).",
                "DefaultValue": "3600"
            }
        ],
        "PlatformTypes": [
            "Windows",
            "Linux",
            "MacOS"
        ],
        "DocumentType": "Command",
        "SchemaVersion": "1.2",
        "LatestVersion": "1",
        "DefaultVersion": "1",
        "DocumentFormat": "JSON",
        "Tags": []
    }
}
```

I need an example using **AWS-RunPowerShellScript** in Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute any SSM run commands from terraform natively. This is **not supported**:

- [Feature Request: AWS SSM run-command should be available as a provisioner](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21316)

Instead, you can use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) to execute AWS CLI's [send-command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html). The other possibility is AWS SDK to do same, but using a lambda function with [aws_lambda_invocation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_invocation).